# Jackson polymorphic deserialization with typeInfo provided by an anySetter mutator

Tags: jackson

I have a yaml file that contains deployment information about a machine cluster that roughly looks like:

```yaml
deployment:
  imageName: generalImageToUse
  machineType: openstack/aws
  flavor: generalFlavorToUse
  machines:
    machine1:
      hostName: machine-1
      flavor: flavorOverride
    machine2:
      hostName: machine-2
      imageName: imageNameOverride
```

This is deserialized into objects as

```java
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
class Deployment {
    private String imageName;
    private MachineType machineType;
    private String flavor;
    private MachineSet machines;

    public class MachineSet {
        private final List<Machine> machines = new ArrayList<>();

        @JsonAnySetter
        public void setMachine(String nameInYaml, Machine machine) {
            machines.add(machine.withDefaultImageName(getImageName())
                                .withDefaultFlavor(getFlavor())
                                .withDefaultType(getMachineType()));
        }

        public List<Machine> getMachines() {
            return machines;
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "machineType")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AwsMachine.class, name = "aws"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = OpenStackMachine.class, name = "openstack")
})
public abstract class Machine {
    private String hostName;
    private String flavor;
    private MachineType machineType;
    private String imageName;

    public abstract String getDefaultFqdn();
    public String getHost() {
        return String.format("%s.%s", host, getDefaultFqdn());
    }
}
```

```java
public class OpenStackMachine extends Machine {
    public final static String DEFAULT_FQDN = "openstack.domain.name";

    @Override
    public String getDefaultFqdn() {
        return DEFAULT_FQDN;
    }
}
```

```java
public class AwsMachine extends Machine {
    public final static String DEFAULT_FQDN = "aws.domain.name";

    @Override
    public String getDefaultFqdn() {
        return DEFAULT_FQDN;
    }
}
```

Which obviously won't work as when the `anySetter` `setMachine(Machine machine)` is called, `Machine` has to be deserialized but the necessary information to discern which type to instantiate is only provided within the method.

Is there any way I can provide this information without creating a custom deserializer/constructing a new object within the `anySetter` method?